# How can I enable group by device type in Computer on Windows 11 File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

I recently switched to Windows 11 and can't manage to set grouping drives in File Explorer by device type like it was on Windows 7. Currently, when is set group by to "type" it look like this:

[image: Current This computer explorer view]

("Urządzenia and dyski" means "Devices and disks")

And what I want to achieve is this grouping as can be seen in Explorer++ (same as on Windows 7):

[image: Old This computer explorer view]

Is there any software or registry patch, that can fix grouping, to be like in older version of Windows?

Comment: In Windows 11 File Explorer, in the window you have, select Group By. Then down at the bottom, choose More ...    A new sub window opens.  Does this help you?  If not you may need a 3rd party File Explorer.